# How to get text of an element on the basis of other element's text value on the same row in the table?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I need to find the text of an element "score" on the basis of other element "SF Lead ID" on the same row.

"SF Lead ID" can be dynamic. for example am using hard coded value here.

```
String sf_id = "00Q1l000003clVhEAI"; //this value is dynamic
String text= dvr.findElement(By.xpath("//*/tr/[contains(text(),'" + sf_id + "')]//*[@id='lead-score']")).getText();
```

[image]

Please look the html structure on the above image. help me to correct the xpath.

Currently its throwing below error -

```
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //*/tr/[contains(text(),'00Q1l000003cldHEAQ')]//*[@id='lead-score'] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//*/tr/[contains(text(),'00Q1l000003cldHEAQ')]//*[@id='lead-score']' is not a valid XPath expression.
  (Session info: chrome=76.0.3809.132)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.38.552518 (183d19265345f54ce39cbb94cf81ba5f15905011),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.6 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/invalid_selector_exception.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract the **score** with respect to **SF Lead ID** you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibilityOfElementLocated()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `cssSelector` and `getText()`:

  ```
  String sf_id = "00Q1l000003clVhEAI";
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("tr[data-sf-lead-id='" + sf_id + "'] td#lead-score"))).getText());
  ```
- Using `xpath` and `getAttribute()`:

  ```
  String sf_id = "00Q1l000003clVhEAI";
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//tr[@data-sf-lead-id='" + sf_id + "']//td[@id='lead-score']"))).getAttribute("innerHTML"));
  ```

Comment: Element not found with this xpath also. Seems some format issue with xpath string.

Comment: @HillHacker My bad, corrected the error, let me know the status.

Comment: removed one "=" in xpath (data-sf-lead-id==) now its working fine for me. @DebanjanB thanks for your quick solution.